# Setting of IIS memory settings for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, memory, application-pool

We are running an ASP.NET app on a web server with 4GB+ of memory in IIS 6.  After reading many articles, it states that we need to set the "maximum memory used" for the Application Pool to 800mb to eliminate the "out of memory exceptions" that are happening for us.  However, what should the "maximum virtual memory" in the Application Pool be set to?  I can't find information as to what that should be set to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to cover is whether you need so much memory in a web application. Our experience tells that a web application should use a reasonable amount of memory. That eliminates out of memory exception forever.

We usually recommend 1024 MB virtual memory as the max virtual memory usage for a pool on x86 machine.

Comment: Is there a formula you use to determine the virtual memory size?

Comment: This is not math, so we have no equation or formula. A profiler can tell you how memory is used by your application. Process Explorer can tell you more about every process.